# Execute function inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I'm using an array of objects to randomly print items in a canvas. Each object should have a different random color, but the way I wrote the code every object gets the same one.

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
    {x: 1, y: 5, r: 10, color: pickColor}, //gets random color
    {x: 2, y: 6, r: 10, color: pickColor}  // should get a different color
    //and so on...
];
```

I tried to replace the `pickColor` variable with a function to be executed inside each object so that they all get a different color, but I can't seem to use this value to pick a color inside my color's array.

This obviously doesn't work :

```
{x: 1, y: 5, r: 10, color: colorList[parseInt(Math.random() * colorList.length)]},
```

EDIT : this code works, the problem came from an apparently unrelated line with no hints in debugging tool.
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Actually that should work. Why do you think it didn't?

Comment: Regarding your fiddle, [don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)!

Comment: a solution like `color: pickMeAColor()` would be better, but yeah, it should work...

Comment: Why doesn't the second piece of code work? It does for me.

Comment: `pickColor` could be a function call. Why not? Use `color: pickColor()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `pickColor` a function and call it multiple times:

```
var colorList = ["#E57373", "#F06292", "#BA68C8", "#9575CD", "#7986CB", "#64B5F6", "#DCE775", "#AED581", "#81C784", "#FFD54F"];

function pickColor() {
    var randIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * colorList.length);
    return colorList[randIndex];
}

var arrayOfObjects = [
    {x: 1, y: 5, r: 10, color: pickColor()},
    {x: 2, y: 6, r: 10, color: pickColor()},
    //and so on...
];
```

The effect is just the same as in your second snippet, except you don't have to repeat yourself for every object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this method is way more cleaner.